# Is Stack Overflow a place for more obscure and proprietary languages?

Tags: discussion

The Lord knows that there are plenty of programming languages out there. However, Stack Overflow seems to attract and cater those who develop in more mainstream languages (C++, C#, Java, Visual Basic, etc.).

Would it be appropriate to post questions and create tags for more obscure languages like [TI-BASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI-BASIC) for Texas Instruments graphing calculators or [PL/I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/I) based languages like PowerOn for Symitar or [AutoLISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoLISP) for AutoCAD just to name a few?

Comment: sure... you can try. You may not get as heavy as a response as you would on a C# tag though.

Comment: Interesting to note, there are already 8 questions in the [autolisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autolisp) tag . None in the others

Comment: But on the bright side, you will get less noise than for those major languages. Mathematica is both proprietary and niche, but it has a small, well-functioning group of users on SO.

Comment: Would it be appropriate? Yes. Effective? May be not always if you're in a hurry to get an answer back. For the more obscure programming languages, I'll tend to track down the forums and the watering holes where those people who know those obscure languages tend to frequent themselves, because I doubt that my questions would get answered in a reasonable timeframe otherwise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is SO a place for more obscure/proprietary languages?

Yes. Stack Overflow is a place for questions on *all* programming languages, provided that they respect the guidelines in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You can't create new tags until you have [1500 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags), but that shouldn't stop you from asking questions.